# How Do I Get the Suggested File Extension for a Document Format?

Tags: owl-api

The OWL API supports many different output document formats. I would like to give the user a choice of which format to use, but each format should have a different file extension, such as `.ttl` for Turtle and `.rdf` for RDF. Does the API provide a way to get a suggested file extension for a given format?

If there isn't a way, I wish there were!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do this at the moment. I have opened an issue for it:
https://github.com/owlcs/owlapi/issues/346

Edit: There's now an Extensions enum that links (some of) the format classes to (some of) the most common file extensions.

Usage: `Iterable formats=Extensions.getCommonExtensions(RDFXMLDocumentFormat.class);'

This is available in the master, version4 and version5 branches. Will be available in the next releases of OWL API.